# How do i create an instance of HtmlElement for testing in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a method I'd like to test in angular.
Here is the method:

```
public checkIfScrolledToBottomOfPanel(event: Event) {

    console.log('event.target instanceof HTMLElement ', event.target instanceof HTMLElement);
    return (
      event.target instanceof HTMLElement &&
      event.target.offsetHeight + event.target.scrollTop >= event.target.scrollHeight
    );
  }
```

My question is how do I mock the event? I have tried the following but it does not work because `event.target instanceof HTMLElement` always returns false.

```
it('should return true if scrolled to the bottom of the panel', () => {
  const mockEvent = {
    target: {
      offsetHeight: 500,
      scrollTop: 300,
      scrollHeight: 100
    }
  } as Event;

  const result = component.checkIfScrolledToBottomOfPanel(mockEvent);
  expect(result).toBe(true);
});
```

Another thing that I tried doing is using `jasmine.createSpyObj` but again it did not work because `instanceof HtmlElement` returned false.

```
const mockEvent = jasmine.createSpyObj('Event', ['target']);
mockEvent.target = jasmine.createSpyObj('HTMLElement', ['offsetHeight', 'scrollTop', 'scrollHeight']);

mockEvent.target.offsetHeight.and.returnValue(100);
mockEvent.target.scrollTop.and.returnValue(100);
mockEvent.target.scrollHeight.and.returnValue(200);
//not working
```

I have also tried `document.createElement('div');` to create the target, but I don't know how to set the `offsetHeight`, `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` since they are `readonly`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of a mock object and type assertion to properly mock the event object. Here's how you can do it:

```js
it('should return true if scrolled to the bottom of the panel', () => {
  // Create a mock event object
  const mockEvent = {
    target: {
      offsetHeight: 500,
      scrollTop: 300,
      scrollHeight: 100
    } as HTMLElement // Type assertion to HTMLElement
  } as Event; // Type assertion to Event

  // Call the method with the mock event
  const result = component.checkIfScrolledToBottomOfPanel(mockEvent);

  // Assert the result
  expect(result).toBe(true);
});
```

Ensure that you use type assertions (as HTMLElement and as Event) to properly define the types of your mock object properties. This allows TypeScript to recognize the properties correctly, including offsetHeight, scrollTop, and scrollHeight, as properties of an HTMLElement